# Correct timing and place for reloading UICollectionView after picking image with UIImagePicker

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have some trouble understanding where I should reload the data inside my UICollectionView, so that the images picked through UIImagePicker from gallery get displayed on the Collection View. This is the code I'm using right now, but I can't seem to understand why it crashes giving me a SIGBRT Error, right after the picker gets dismissed. I set the delegates through storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var addImage: UIButton!
var imagesArray : [UIImage] = []
@IBAction func buttonPickerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if imagesArray.count < 5 {
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
    addImage.isHidden = true }
}
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewImages: UICollectionView!
let picker = UIImagePickerController()



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imagesArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageDisplayed.image = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
    collectionViewImages.delegate = self
    if imagesArray.count < 5 {
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        imagesArray.append(selectedImage) //whatever space is free] = selectedImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.collectionViewImages.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Maximum amount of images reached", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default) { (action) in
        return}
        alert.addAction(action)
        picker.dismiss(animated:true ,completion:nil)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)}

}
```

---------- UPDATE ----------
I've also created a button in the main VC, with an action so that it would trigger the collectionView to reload when pressed, but still no luck. No matter at what time I press reload, when I do the app crashed with a NSException error. I made sure also the array is not empty when displaying the images. Any ideas?

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self. collectionViewImages.reloadData()
}

Comment: Change your this ( self.collectionViewImages.reloadData() ) line to above one...

Comment: Let me know if it works or not...

Comment: I've tried it already before posting, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set data source for `collectionViewImages`. And reload `collectionViewImages` in `picker` completion handler.

Comment: I set both delegate and dataSource through storyboard, I've tried the completion, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Apparently the problem was that I was using the idenxPath.row method to get the index, whereas I should have used a indexPath.item to access the images Array.